# MAMP vhost: "The requested URL / was not found on this server."

Tags: macos, apache, codeigniter, mamp, vhosts

I want to open a Codegniter project on virtual host, the steps I've done are as follows:

1. in **httpd.conf**, uncommented this line

> `Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.con

2. in **httpd.conf**, Allowed SymLink Override .

> <'Directory /> .
>   Options Indexes .
>    FollowSymLinks
>   AllowOverride All .
>   <./Directory>

3. Added the virtual host path to **httpd-vhosts.conf** .

> <.VirtualHost *:80> .
>          DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-project" .
>          ServerName my-project.local .
>   <./VirtualHost>` .

I made sure the paths are correct in Terminal by using  `cd ~` and `cd my/project/path` and typing `pwd` and it gave me the correct path.

4. added the path to the **hosts** file .

> 127.0.0.1       my-project.local

5. On **MAMP**, changed Apache Port to 80, and restarted MAMP .

And after finishing all the exact same steps on the tutorials I've read/watched, After I visit `my-project.local` I get [this Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R3T9.png) Error.
I revised all the steps and made sure everything is correct but still get that message.
Any help will be MUCH appreciated.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGPXP.png) is the content of my **.htaccess** file.
I have tried deleting its content and changing it to Allow all but nothing changed.

*PS: dots '.' in <.> tags are just to skip markdown ignoring <> tags and are not typos*

Comment: Yes, I did restarted MAMP multiple times after I finished the configuration.

Comment: Just looked, couldn't find 'NameVirtualHost' in any of the files I worked in.
Where can I find it?

Comment: "PS: dots '.' in `<`.`>` tags are just to skip markdown ignoring `<>` tags and are not typos" — Click the *code* button to format them as code!